# VBA macro to change cell content every X rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chronological data set organized by clusters of age categories. I have two operations that I need to perform:

1. I need to find the last instance in the data set of a single-digit number (1-9), change it to an asterisk (*), and proceed backwards to the beginning, repeating this change every 7 cells.
2. Then I need to select the adjacent cell above the asterisk and change that content to an asterisk (*), and proceed upwards every 25 cells repeating the change.

It sounds convoluted but must done backwards, starting at the bottom.

I have scant VBA experience and am having much difficulty. I have tried looking into RegExp to search and replace but could not figure it out. I have tried using MOD to automate counting 7 or 25 cells upwards but alas could not.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: At the very least, show us some sample data showing before and after results. However, this is not a code writing service, and you should show your attempt and explain what did not work. We are not here to complete your project from start to end, but rather help you along the way. We need more info to actually help you here

Comment: Is the data set text that contains digits, or a numeric value. Is it like `Q10239` or `8.8273` ?

Comment: @urdearboy Thank you. I do not have results to share because my pathetic attempt at writing a script would not even execute. Feel free to recommend a beginner's book to learn VBA.

Comment: If you don't know VBA, you could always go with formula's

Comment: @JvdV That was my first instinct, and might go with that for expediency. It's a work place request for a different team and I was hoping to come up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't provided any details of what the data looks like, I will provide with a very general answer with the `VBA` functions that you need to write the code *on your own*.

If you have a reference to a cell via a `.Range()` object use the following functions

The following assumes the following to be defined

```
Dim r as Range
```

- `x = r.Value` get the value of the cell.
- `x = r.Cels(i,j).Value` get the value of the `i`-th row and `j`-th column in a table starting from `r`. To get the value 7 below you write `x = r.Cells(7,1).Value`
- `Set r = r.Offset(i,j)` move `i` rows down and `j` across. These can be positive, zero or negative. For example to move up one row, `r.Offset(-1,0)`
- `Set r = r.Resize(n,m)` expand the range into a table with `n` rows and `m` columns starting from `r` on the top left.
- `x = r.Resize(n,m).Value` returns a 2D array from the table of values. Works in reverse also `r.Resize(n,m).Value = x` to assign multiple values in one fell swoop.

Now, depending on the number of rows you are dealing with, I suggest you read all the values into memory, loop through the data to find what you are looking for, make the changes and write back.

Assume your data starts at `C3`. In VBA code window for the sheet (not a module) write something like this

```
Dim n As Long, i As Long, index As Long
Dim r As Range, target As String, j As Long

'Find how many rows are filled
Set r = Range("C3")
n = Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Set r = r.Resize(n, 1)

'Read all the values into memory
Dim vals() As Variant
vals = r.Value

'Loop from the end and find the target digit
target = "7"

' Start from bottom and search contents for the target digit
i = n
Do While i >= 1
    index = InStr(1, vals(i, 1), target, vbTextCompare)
    If index > 0 Then
        ' Found it. 'i' contains the row the target is found.
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i - 1
Loop

If i = 0 Then
    'None found
    Exit Sub
End If

' Start from i and go back every 7 to change the value into a '*'
For i = i To 1 Step -7
    vals(i, 1) = "*"
    ' Start from the row above (i-1) and go back every 25
    For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -25
        vals(j, 1) = "*"
    Next j
Next i

'Write the changes back to the sheet
r.Value = vals
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing some explanation, even if the initial question is vague. I will go through this and see if I can come up with my own script, and will share what I find.

Comment: What is the main reason for using the code sheet rather than a module? Based on the logic of the data sorting that I'm working on, I had imagined that it would not be difficult to write a module.

Comment: So that `Range()` objects apply to the sheet only and not to the implicit `ActiveSheet`. Essentially on `Sheet1` the expression `Range("A3")` is treated as `Sheet1.Range("A3")`, but on a module `Range("A3")` is treated as `ActiveSheet.Range("A3")` which can be quite different. So to make _sure_ the program does what it is intended to do, if it manipulates data on a sheet, added it the Worksheet code and not in a general module.